# Rscript: command not found

Tags: r, installation, terminal

I'm working with R for a while, and I always worked with Rstudio, I tried just now to run a Rscript command in terminal (I have a mac..) and I got this error-

```
>Rscript script.R
 -bash: Rscript: command not found
```

when I tried to open R in the terminal I go the same error-

```
>R
-bash: R: command not found
```

I can run R code with the Rstudio and the R application, but I know there is a way to run R throw the terminal.
Did I miss something when I installed R on my computer? do I need to add R to my PATH?

thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like R is not on your PATH.

Comment: @T.G. This is for sure, try to install it again , one solution ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"  brew tap homebrew/science
brew install r

Comment: Set the path for `Rscript.exe` in the environment variables to run the script through terminal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Steps to run R script through `Windows command prompt`

1. Set the `PATH` variable for `Rscript.exe`in the environment variables. `Rscript.exe` can be found inside `bin` folder of `R`. Set the path for `Rscript.exe` to use `Rscript` command in Windows command prompt. To check if `Rscript.exe` has been set environmentally or not, type `Rscript` in command prompt. The follwoing message should come.

[image]

2. Go to Command Prompt, set the path where your `.R` file is there.
3. Run the following command: Here `abcd.R` is present under `Documents` folder. So I set path and then run `Rscript abcd.R`

[image]

Comment: I needed to restart the PC after I changed the path.

Answer (score 5):

For those who stumbled upon this but use a mac, you might find this useful.  I recently downloaded and installed R and RStudio through the CRAN site.  I didn't do it through homebrew.  Since I downloaded this install directly from the site, it DID NOT add the RScript executable to my `/usr/local/bin` directory.

I have `locate` on my mac so I did a quick lookup:

```sh
locate RScript
```

And I found it here:

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/bin/Rscript
```

What I had to do was create a symbolic link to my `/usr/local/bin` directory to get it to work:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/bin/Rscript Rscript
```

Now I'm able to run Rscript through the command line.  This may help someone else out there.