# Environment Variables not recognized when calling Run in WScript.Shell object

Tags: vba, shell

If I run the command `Rscript "C:/TEMP/test.R"` in the command line it works and my script runs as expected. Once I try to run it in my VBA code it does not recognize the Rscript as a valid command.

```
Dim shell_obj As Object
Set shell_obj = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim errorCode As Integer
errorCode = shell_obj.Run("Rscript ""C:/TEMP/test.R""", 1, True)
```

When I looked into the PATH variable being used by the WScript.Shell I saw that it does not include the System Variables with the Rscript path inside of it.

```
Dim shell_obj As Object
Dim wshSystemEnv As Object
Set shell_obj = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' This one does not include the path to the Rscript'
Debug.Print shell_obj.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PATH%")
Set wshSystemEnv = shell_obj.Environment("SYSTEM")
' This one includes the path to the Rscript'
Debug.Print wshSystemEnv("PATH")
```

Can I force the the WScript.Shell object to use the System environment? Or at least use its variables?

Cmd:
[image]

VBA (version 1):

[image]

VBA (version 2):

[image]

Comment: In VBA, just use `Environ("path")`.  No WScript or RScript necessary.

Comment: So your problem is that the system isn't automatically checking the path where `rscript.exe` is located, correct? Do you know what the correct location of that fie is?   (One you determine that, we can add it to the existing path.)

Comment: I know it in my computer. But the code may be used in someone else's machine with a different version of R (which changes the path). So putting a fix path would not solve the problem.

Comment: You had not mentioned that there are other computers involved.  I'm now confused: your question says you can run it from the command prompt but not from VBA. The first step is to get it running on yours, even if the path is hard-coded for now. Where is `rscript.exe` located on **your** computer? Once you get this working on **your** machine then we can worry about others...

Comment: Based on the research I've done, this file has greatly varying paths as there isn't a "standard" install location for the `R` package. I can help with code to programmatically locate the file, but I'm not going to bother until the script runs properly on *your* machine with a *known* path.

Comment: The path to the Rscript is inside my System Enviroment Variables so once I call it in the `cmd` it work.If I run the same command in VBA it does not work. If I hard-code the path to Rscript it works.

Comment: Can you **please** [edit] your question to add a screen shot of the command line statement that works, and a screen shot of the `Shell` statement that does not work.  I am 99% sure i know what's wrong but I can't verify without that information.

Comment: If you're running the `Shell` statement with `c:\ ` in it (like your example) shows, then **that is the problem** and I bet you're not doing that at the command prompt.  Specifying an absolute path *overrules* the system's **path** variable.  The command line and the `Shell` command need to be Identical!

Comment: I added more example screen shots to the bottom of the answer below.

Comment: I had the same issue reversed: i was seeing the correct dir in `ExpandEnvironmentStrings`, but not in `Environment("USER")`. Restarting Office worked for me.

Comment: there's probably no difference, but you could also try adding the reference to Microsoft Script Host to get early binding

Answer (score 2):

> ### ***EDIT***: **See bottom of post.**

Hopefully you'll find some use in my (lengthy) take on this... :-)

---

### Testing for command-line readiness

Any command ([including an `RScript`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11598613/8112776)) that can be run *as-is* from the Windows command-line can *also* be run with either [the *VBA* `Shell` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/shell-function) or the [Windows `WScript.Shell` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb774107.aspx).

The issue is, your `cmd` string is **not** command-line ready. This can be confirmed by hitting <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and pasting the contents of your `cmd` string variable:

```
Rscript "**path**/test.R"
```

I don't currently have [`rscript.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3412911/8112776) installed but I suspect you will get an error if you try running your command manually in either the *Run* window or on the command line.  If it doesn't run there it obviously won't run with in a VBA *Shell*.

As I understand it, the double asterisk is a [Java notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18722471/8112776) the way you are using it, and in *R* is the [same as a `^` caret character](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/190702/215637), which is for calculating exponents.

---

### Referencing an environment variable

To return the [Windows `PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#DOS,_OS/2,_and_Windows) in *VBA*, you would use [VBA's `Environ` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/environ-function).

To insert the value environment variable [inline at the command line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Syntax), you would surround it with `%`percent`%` symbols, like `%path%`

---

### Windows' `PATH` environment variable

`PATH` does not return a single folder. It's a **list of folders** that Windows should check to find an executable file that one attempts to run.

> <sup>When a command is entered in a command shell or a system call is made by a program to execute a program, the system first searches the current working directory and then searches the path, examining each directory from left to right, looking for an executable filename that matches the command name given.</sup>
>
> <sup>The Windows system directory (typically `C:\WINDOWS\system32`) is typically the first directory in the path, followed by many (but not all) of the directories for installed software packages.</sup>

An example a default value of `PATH` ([from a fresh install of Windows 7](https://superuser.com/a/787583/774713)) is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

As with `%path%, this includes`%SystemRoot%` which, by default on Windows 7 is the string:

```
C:\Windows
```

---

### Checking environment variables

You can verify the value of your `PATH` environment label:

- Hit <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
- Type `cmd` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. (A command line window should open.)
- Type or paste `echo %path%` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The contents of the Window `PATH` environment variable will be displayed.

You can also check environment variables from within Windows:

- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> and type `env` (to search)
- Click `Edit the system environment variables`. (There is a similar option *"...for your account"* which is not *quite* the same.)
- Click <sub><sub>[image: <kbd>Environment Variables...</kbd>]</sub></sub>
  [image: img]

> <sup>**Note:** Although **you technically *can* change** the `PATH` in this window, **I would not recommend doing so**, especially with `PATH` since it is split up into System and User folders, and Windows likes certain folders in certain areas, and some changes don't take effect until reboot but others do, and *blah blah blah*, trust me: it's easier to do from the command line.</sup>

---

## *What's wrong with your code?*

Therefore it based on all of this, it appears that the command you're trying to run is:

```
Rscript "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem/test.R"
```

...which obviously *will not work*.

---

### Get or set the current working folder/directory

I can only speculate as to *what you're trying to accomplish*.

I suspect you didn't intend to return the entire `PATH` variable, but are only interested in the ***current working folder***.

If so, **you don't need to specify a folder at all**.  `Shell` already commands execute in the "current" folder.

One way you can check which [directory or folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)#Folder_metaphor) is current, is with the [VBA `CurDir()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/curdir-function), like:

```
Debug.Print CurDir()
```

The value of `CurDir` can be changed with [the `ChDir` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/chdir-statement).

---

### Similar functions

Note that the `CurDur()` command is often confused with similar functions like:

- [`Application.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-path-property-excel) which returns the path to the Excel application, or,
- [`ActiveWorkbook.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-activeworkbook-property-excel) which returns the location that the active workbook is saved (or an empty string if it's unsaved).

---

## Possible Solution: <sub><sup>*(How to run an `rScript` in the current path in VBA)*</sup></sub>

- If your *R* script and the `rscript.exe` are *both* in the current working folder, run it with just one line of VBA:

  ```
  Shell "rscript.exe test.R", vbNormalFocus
  ```
- If you require VBA to **wait** for execution of the Shell command to complete before resuming VBA, then you can you just this one line:

  ```
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "rscript.exe test.R", vbNormalFocus, True
  ```

---

### More Information:

<sup>I generally make a point of including links to any sites I used to verify my answers, so this must be my *most-researched answer yet* because I've never had a list this long... and I left some off out this time!</sup>

- Stack Overflow : [**Running *R* scripts from *VBA***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11598613/8112776)
- MSDN : [**`Shell` Function** (VBA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/shell-function)
- MSDN : [**`Environ` Function** (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/environ-function)
- *R*-Bloggers : [**Passing arguments to an *R* script from command lines**](https://www.r-bloggers.com/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/)
- Stack Overflow : [**`R.exe`, `Rcmd.exe`, `Rscript.exe` and `Rterm.exe`**: what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3412911/8112776)
- Stack Exchange: Statistics : [**Double star ** in *R*?**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/190702/215637)
- Wikipedia : [**PATH** (variable)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#DOS,_OS/2,_and_Windows)
- Stack Overflow : [**Default values of `PATH` variable in Windows 10**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45072976/8112776)
- SuperUser : [**Default `PATH` for Windows 7**](https://superuser.com/a/787583/774713)
- MSDN : [**`CurDir()` Function** (VBA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/curdir-function)
- MSDN : [**`ChDir()` Statement** (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/chdir-statement)
- MSDN : [**`Application.Path`** (Excel/VBA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-path-property-excel)
- MSDN : [**`ActiveWorkbook.Path`** (Excel/VBA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-activeworkbook-property-excel)
- Stack Overflow : [**Wait for `Shell` command to complete**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952009/8112776)
- MSDN Forums : [**Difference between `wscript.shell` and `shell.application`**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1c348b77-18a8-4956-8561-fd97d4585cd3/?forum=scripting)
- Stack Overflow : [**Steps to run R script through Windows command prompt**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38456622/8112776)

---

---

> ## One More Demo of What's Wrong With Your Code:
>
> > I have a batch file named `test.bat` located in `C:\WINDOWS`.  My `PATH` environment variable contains `C:\WINDOWS` (among other things).
>
> If I go to the command prompt in root folder `C:\` and type `test.bat`:
>
> [image: img1]
>
> ...it runs properly (even though my file is not in that folder... since the `c:\windows` folder is within the `PATH` variable.)
>
> ---
>
> ***However***, if I go to the command prompt  and type `C:\test.bat`:
>
> [image: img2]
>
> ...it does **not** work. It cannot find the file **because I *specified* a folder where the file is *not* located**.
>
> --- In VBA, if I run the command `Shell "test.bat",1`:
>
> [image: img3]
>
> ...it runs properly (even though my file is not in that folder... since the `c:\windows` folder is within the `PATH` variable.)
>
> ---
>
> ***However***, if in VBA I run the command `Shell "c:\test.bat",1`:
>
> [image: img4]
>
> ...it does **not** work. It cannot find the file **because I**specified* a folder where the file is *not* located**.
>
> ---
>
> > Both VBA and the `Shell` command are **behaving the *same way***, when given the *same information*.

Comment: nicely covered!

Comment: I'm only using one programming language in my code which is VBA. The **path** is just to hide the actual path that would be something like "C:/...". The command works fine in the command line. I'll edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: As you can see in the pictures that I've added to the question, I'm running as I would run inside a normal CMD. The path is not wrong... The thing is that **the PATH variable used by the Shell does not contain all the values that are inside the System Environment PATH**. If I run the second part of the code with the debugs, the  **wshSystemEnv("PATH")** contains the path to the Rscript.exe and the **shell_obj.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PATH%")** does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently modified the system PATH variable, you must restart the Office application you are running VBA from. VBA sends WScript the path variable and only rereads it on a restart. On restart, it will reread the PATH variable from the system and send the new correct path to WScript.

I had the same issue. I had updated the system PATH variable, but the WScript.Shell object was being passed the path variable from Excel rather than reading from the system. Excel had read the path at startup and was not aware it had changed. Once I closed Excel and reopened, WScript had the updated path variable and my script execute successfully.